# Syntax error when output a set of record in PostgreSQL C function

Tags: c, postgresql

I wrote a C function for PostgreSQL that returns a set of records. According to *PostgreSQL Server Programming*, I typed code like this:

```
#include "postgres.h"
#include "fmgr.h"
#include "utils/array.h"
#include "executor/spi.h"
#include "utils/builtins.h"
#include "funcapi.h"

PG_MODULE_MAGIC;

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(iknnLP);

int dim;
Heap res;

Datum
iknnLP(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {
int call_cntr;
    int call_cntr;
    int max_calls;
    FuncCallContext *funcctx;

    if (SRF_IS_FIRSTCALL()) {
        MemoryContext oldcontext;
        // create a function context for cross-call persistence
        funcctx = SRF_FIRSTCALL_INIT();
        // switch to memory context appropriate for multiple function calls
        oldcontext = MemoryContextSwitchTo(funcctx->multi_call_memory_ctx);

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //                     My Code
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        funcctx->max_calls = res.length;  // res is a structure
        if (get_call_result_type(fcinfo, NULL, &funcctx->tuple_desc) != TYPEFUNC_COMPOSITE)
            ereport(ERROR, (errcode(ERRCODE_FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED),
            errmsg("function returning record called in context" "that cannot accept type record")));
        BlessTupleDesc(funcctx->tuple_desc);

        // restore memory context
        MemoryContextSwitchTo(oldcontext);
    }

    funcctx = SRF_PERCALL_SETUP();
    call_cntr = funcctx->call_cntr;
    max_calls = funcctx->max_calls;

    if (call_cntr < max_calls) {
        HeapTuple rettuple;
        Datum *retvals;
        bool *retnulls;

        retvals = (Datum*)palloc0(sizeof(Datum) * dim);
        retnulls = (bool*)palloc0(sizeof(bool) * dim);
        for (i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
            retvals[i] = Int32GetDatum(res.rec[call_cntr + 1].vals[i]);
            retnulls[i] = false;
        }
        rettuple = heap_form_tuple(funcctx->tuple_desc, retvals, retnulls);
        SRF_RETURN_NEXT(funcctx, HeapTupleGetDatum(rettuple));
    }
    else {
        SRF_RETURN_DONE(funcctx);
    }
}
```

And my .sql.in file is here

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION iknnLP(text)
  RETURNS SETOF record
  AS 'MODULE_PATHNAME', 'iknnLP'
  LANGUAGE C STRICT;
```

Unfortunately, I got syntax error while I call this function in PostgreSQL command line:

```
select iknnLP('find 3 neighbour of (a0,a1)(31,32) from test') as(a int, b int, distance float);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: ...hbour of (a0,a1)(31,32) from test') as(a int, b ...
                                                 ^
```

PS: I got a warning when making files:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘heap_form_tuple’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
rettuple = heap_form_tuple(funcctx->tuple_desc, retvals, retnulls);
^
```

Anyone knows the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL syntax is not entirely conformant. You are trying to assign field names and types to a record using the construct for aliases.

Since you are returning a `SET OF record` you should really use the function in the `FROM` clause with an alias for the record set:

```
SELECT a, b, distance
FROM iknnLP('find 3 neighbour of (a0,a1)(31,32) from test') AS x(a int, b int, distance float);
```